# lps d2 command removes masterColo field for symlink enabled clusters

Tags: d, symlink

We are trying to onboard a symlink enabled cluster to lps
while migrating the cluster from d2.src to lps-d2, ei seems to work fine. But when we try to do “lps d2 update” on prod, it looks like lps is removing the "masterColo" field.

```css
lps d2 update -f prod-lva1 -c StickyRoutingServer 
Using the certificate found in /export/home/vnosovsk/.maestro-user-certs/prod
diff --git a/export/home/vnosovsk/.maestro/old_StickyRoutingServer b/export/home/vnosovsk/.maestro/new_StickyRoutingServer
index 403d095..ffc4288 100644
--- a/export/home/vnosovsk/.maestro/old_StickyRoutingServer
+++ b/export/home/vnosovsk/.maestro/new_StickyRoutingServer
@@ -1,18 +1,17 @@
 {
     "darkClusters": {},
-    "masterColo": "urn:li:fabric:prod-lva1",
     "name": "StickyRoutingServer",
     "partitionConfiguration": {
         "type": "NONE"
     },
     "peerColos": [
         "urn:li:fabric:PROD-ELA4",
         "urn:li:fabric:prod-lva1",
         "urn:li:fabric:prod-ltx1",
         "urn:li:fabric:prod-lsg1",
         "urn:li:fabric:prod-lor1"
     ],
     "sslSessionValidationStrings": [
         "stickyrouting"
     ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the "lps" CLI you are using by running "lps -h". This issue was fixed in version 1.0.14. If the version is older than this, it means Assembler is no longer updating the CLI on the host where you are running the command anymore. Most likely because of an OS that is no longer supported (e.g. RHEL6). Please try running the command on lva-shell01.prod.linkedin.com or ltx-shell01.prod.linkedin.com.

If you have any further issues, please submit a support ticket at go/supportal.